# How do i get the ID from parent table and JOIN from child table to run the query.

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one is students and another is schools. I am using a FK to call school id ( `scid` ) to the students table.

Students

```
+------+---------+-----+-----------+
| stid | student | age | school_id |
+------+---------+-----+-----------+
|  1   | John    |  26 |         2 |
|  2   | Susan   |  24 |         1 |
+------+---------+-----+-----------+
```

schools

```
+------+------------+-----------+
| scid | schoolname | syllabus  |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  1   | school1    | syllabus1 |
|  2   | school2    | syllabus2 |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

The view page displays all the details where i am using a id to get the details from the students table and using a join to get the information from school table.

```
Student name: John
Age: 26
School: School 2
```

I need to use the id for students and use the join to get the name from the school. How do i do that. I came up with this, but how do i use the id with this.

```
SELECT schools.name
FROM schools
    LEFT JOIN students
        ON students.school_id=schools.scid;
```

Comment: `select student, age, schoolname from students stdu inner join schools sch on(stdu.school_id=sch.scid ) where stdu.stid = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
select student, age, schoolname 
 from students stdu inner join schools sch 
on(stdu.school_id=sch.scid ) 
 where stdu.stid = 1
```

> The `MySQL INNER JOIN` clause matches rows in one table with rows in other tables and allows you to query rows that contain columns from both tables.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html